# ImageJ (plugin Java): auto threshold method doesn't work

Tags: java, image-processing, imagej

I try to write Java Plugin to ImageJ, which should:

- Load image (24-bit).
- Do some preprocessing operations.
- **Threshold the image in numerous of methods.**
- Do some other operations.

I have problem with threshold operation. Part of my code looks like this:

```
Opener opener = new Opener();
ImagePlus imp = opener.openImage(source);
// Preprocessing
IJ.run("Threshold..." , method);
// Other operations e.g. "open", "outline" etc.
IJ.saveAs(destination);
```

My goal is to get binarized image in various methods (e.g. "Default", "Huang", "Intermodes", "IsoData", "Li" etc.).
Only way which I can get binarized image is to run:

```
IJ.run(imp, "8-bit", "");
IJ.run(imp, "Make Binary", "");
```

however, I get an image binarized by only one method.
How to do automatic threshold by running Java code (ImageJ plugin)?

Comment: this does not answer the question: maybe you should openImaj (http://www.openimaj.org/) give a try. There are some methods concerning threshold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The auto-threshold methods in the [Threshold dialog](http://imagej.nih.gov/ij/docs/guide/146-28.html#sub:Threshold...[T]) all are algorithms working on single channel (8-bit or 16-bit) images. In the [Color Threshold](http://imagej.nih.gov/ij/docs/guide/146-28.html#sub:Color-Threshold...) dialog, they are applied exclusively to the *Brightness* channel of your 24-bit color image.

To reproduce this in Java, use the following code:

```
IJ.run(imp, "HSB Stack", "");
imp.setSlice(3);
IJ.setAutoThreshold(imp, "Triangle dark");
Prefs.blackBackground = true;
IJ.run(imp, "Convert to Mask", "only");
```

(Converting your image to 8-bit is nothing else than using the *Brightness* channel, discarding the Hue and Saturation information. Unless you really make use of the other sliders in the *Color Threshold* dialog, you can just as well convert the image to 8-bit before applying the threshold.)

Comment: Your code look correct, but when I change method (e.g. method=IsoData, method=Huang etc.) I'm allways getting result as I use "default" method.

Comment: The code was missing an `IJ.setAutoThreshold` call. I edited my answer accordingly. Apparently, the method chosen in the "Convert to Mask" dialog is being ignored, which might be a bug: you can report this via *Help > Report a bug* in the menu.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to use the [`IJ.run`](http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/developer/api/ij/IJ.html#run-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) method the wrong way. The first parameter is a string containing an ImageJ command and the second parameter is a string containing the options of this command. From the documentation:

> public static void run(java.lang.String command,
>                          java.lang.String options)
>
> Runs an ImageJ command, with options that are passed to the
>   GenericDialog and OpenDialog classes. Does not return until the
>   command has finished executing. To generate run() calls, start the
>   recorder (Plugins/Macro/Record) and run commands from the ImageJ menu
>   bar.

You can also use the GUI to record a macro, `Plugins->Macros->Record...`, *set the record mode to Java*, and select the methods and threshold values you want. You will obtain something like this:

```
// Color Thresholder 1.49i
// Autogenerated macro, single images only!
min=newArray(3);
max=newArray(3);
filter=newArray(3);
a=getTitle();
run("HSB Stack");
run("Convert Stack to Images");
selectWindow("Hue");
rename("0");
selectWindow("Saturation");
rename("1");
selectWindow("Brightness");
rename("2");
min[0]=139;
max[0]=254;
filter[0]="pass";
min[1]=48;
max[1]=110;
filter[1]="pass";
min[2]=189;
max[2]=255;
filter[2]="pass";
for (i=0;i<3;i++){
  selectWindow(""+i);
  setThreshold(min[i], max[i]);
  run("Convert to Mask");
  if (filter[i]=="stop")  run("Invert");
}
imageCalculator("AND create", "0","1");
imageCalculator("AND create", "Result of 0","2");
for (i=0;i<3;i++){
  selectWindow(""+i);
  close();
}
selectWindow("Result of 0");
close();
selectWindow("Result of Result of 0");
rename(a);
// Colour Thresholding-----------------
```

Comment: Be careful, the code recorded by the *Threshold Color* plugin is **macro code**, not Java. You can however get valid Java code with the recorder if you convert your RGB image to 8-bit first, or you split the channels via *Image > Color > Split Channels*.

Comment: @JanEglinger you are right that above code is not Java code - it is not useful in that case.
If I change image to 8-bits I lost part of information. What if I split channels? Can I do binarization as effective as with 24-bit image?

Comment: Ortomala Lokni - My code (after modifications) is from "Plugins->Macros->Record...". Threshold metod recorded is: "//IJ.run("Threshold...");". As you can see at the begining there are "//"  (Java comment sign) - probably because in Threshold Color window there is no options like "OK" or "Apply". I can't figure out what is correct form of threshold comand for 24-bit images.

Comment: @JanEglinger I splitted channels as you suggested. I was looking at macro records while using threshold method on 8-bits image. There is Java method: "IJ.setAutoThreshold(imp, "Li dark")" which works fine on 8-bit images. I'm looking for analogous method for 24-bit images.

Comment: @trojek If you **set the record mode to Java**, you obtain valid Java code. The code in my answer is valid java code. All methods are static methods of the [IJ class](http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/developer/api/ij/IJ.html). You juste have to do a static import like this : `import static ij.IJ.*`

Comment: @OrtomalaLokni How do you want to use static functions outsie of the class (in plugin class)? it doesn't suit to object oriented programming approach.

Comment: @trojek Sure you can, read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/static-import.html